# Minimum gap between consecutive energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Assume a standard one-particle, non-relativistic Hamiltonian of the form
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(r)
\end{equation}
and denote its eigenvalues as $E_{n,\tau}$, where $n$ is the principal quantum number and $\tau$ represents all the other quantum numbers, if any.

**Is it possible to derive a lower bound on $E_{n+1,\tau}-E_{n,\tau}$, i.e. on the energy gap between consecutive levels with the same quantum numbers?** My intuition is that long-range potentials should allow smaller gaps (cf. the Coulomb potential, where the gap gets infinitely small as $n\to\infty$), but I haven't managed to express this quantitatively.

Comment: Take a look at the hydrogen spectrum in the limit of Rydberg atoms. What's not quantitative about the formula? It tells you the exact spectrum. You could, of course, ask about spectral properties of operators with the above form where $V(r)$ has a certain decay characteristic, but that's really a question for mathematics, where it has been explored plenty.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268872/what-is-the-lowest-energy-atomic-transition-ever-detected-and-identified (which has a link to a question about *::drumroll::* Rydberg atoms.

Comment: Well, that's what I was alluding to when I mentioned the Coulomb potential. But can the minimum gap (if it exists, that is) be expressed as a functional of the potential?

Comment: That's a problem handled in functional analysis. You need to talk to the mathematicians about that. It is, in its general form, a complicated problem, by the way. There is no simple answer and the relevant answers lead you far away from the realm of $L^2$ functions, which are pretty much the only ones we care about in physics.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  How can consecutive energy levels have the same quantum numbers?  You have not defined the potential.  Are you asking if there is a general result applying to all potentials?

Comment: This is a very interesting question that the comments don't do justice to. The fact that $1/r$ has small gaps and $x^2$ doesn't is interesting. I'm tempted to say that any potential bounded above has arbitrarily small bound state energy gaps, but that's clearly untrue (e.g. it fails for $-\delta(x)$).

Comment: @sammy gerbil, consecutive energy levels with the same quantum numbers *except the principal one*. I'm asking if there is a way to express the gap as a functional of the potential.

Comment: @sammygerbil I find the problem statement perfectly clear. The OP is asking about holding all other quantum numbers fixed, such as the magnetic quantum number.