# How can an $n=25$ Rydberg state exist in a solid? What does the wave function look like?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics, orbitals, rydberg-states

Phys.org's April 15, 2022 [Ancient Namibian stone could hold key to future quantum computers](https://phys.org/news/2022-04-ancient-namibian-stone-key-future.html) begins:

> A special form of light made using an ancient Namibian gemstone could be the key to new light-based quantum computers, which could solve long-held scientific mysteries, according to new research led by the University of St Andrews.
>
> The research, conducted in collaboration with scientists at Harvard University in the US, Macquarie University in Australia and Aarhus University in Denmark and published in Nature Materials, used a naturally mined cuprous oxide ($\require{mhchem} \ce{Cu_2O}$) gemstone from Namibia to produce Rydberg polaritons, the largest hybrid particles of light and matter ever created.

and links to Orfanakis et al. (2022) in Nature Materials [Rydberg exciton–polaritons in a $\ce{Cu_2O}$ microcavity](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/s41563-022-01230-4) (also available at [ohadi.group](https://ohadi.group/publication/orfanakis-natmat-2022/orfanakis-natmat-2022.pdf)). The abstract:

> **Giant Rydberg excitons with principal quantum numbers as high as $n=25$ have been observed** in cuprous oxide ($\ce{Cu_2O}$), a semiconductor in which the exciton diameter can become as large as ∼1 μm. The giant dimension of these excitons results in excitonic interaction enhancements of orders of magnitude. Rydberg exciton–polaritons, formed by the strong coupling of Rydberg excitons to cavity photons, are a promising route to exploit these interactions and achieve a scalable, strongly correlated solid-state platform. However, the strong coupling of these excitons to cavity photons has remained elusive. Here, by embedding a thin $\ce{Cu_2O}$ crystal into a Fabry–Pérot microcavity, we achieve strong coupling of light to $\ce{Cu_2O}$ Rydberg excitons up to n = 6 and demonstrate the formation of $\ce{Cu_2O}$ Rydberg exciton–polaritons. These results pave the way towards realizing strongly interacting exciton–polaritons and exploring strongly correlated phases of matter using light on a chip.

**Question:** How can an $n=25$ Rydberg state exist in a solid? What does the wave function look like?

I normally think of [Rydberg atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom) and [Rydberg states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_state) in general as existing only at atoms (or hydrogen atom-like<sup>1</sup> systems e.g. muonium) quite well isolated from perturbations, so usually in vacuum (in astrophysics and in the laboratory) and often cooled in an atomic trap of some kind, rather than inside a solid.

This is an *exciton* which is still a hydrogen-like fixed positive charge with a bound negative charge with a large wave function. Wikipedia's [Wannier–Mott exciton; Equations for 3D semiconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exciton#Equations_for_3D_semiconductors) doesn't have too much to say about such a high level of excitation or details of the wave function.

As to "What does the wave function look like?" I would expect it to be overall spherical in nature, but is it *corrugated* by the Bloch potential of the crystal lattice in some way?

---

<sup>1</sup>cf. [this answer to *What is a "hydrogen-like" or "hydrogenic" atom?*](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/80320/16035)

Potentially related:

- [What's the highest-$n$ Rydberg state that's been created and detected experimentally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339385/83380)
- [Which is larger, all known, bound nuclear energy levels, or known, bound atomic energy levels?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268806/83380)

Comment: I think you can kind of think of this in terms of effective masses. The lattice is complicated but who cares? In other words the specific details of the lattice are kind of wrapped up in the band structure and effectively the surrounding lattice is averaged out. Thus in effect the hole and electron are free to move and are accelerated by fields as determined by the effective masses, and the potential the electron sees is dominated by hole so the potential looks like that of the positive charge, and the excited states  look like the excited states in that potential.